# A document library with custom content type displays the different icon while creating new document

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type

I have created a document library declaratively with document based content type. But when I click on new document the icon is displayed of item instead of word.

Below is the example:

[image]

List tempalte is:

```
<ListTemplate
        Name="Documents"
        Type="11108"
        BaseType="1"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        DisallowContentTypes="false"
        Sequence="110"      
        DisplayName="QMSDocuments"          
        Image="/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png"
        DocumentTemplate="121"/>

<!-- Parent ContentType: Document (0x0101) -->
<ContentType ID="0x0101001EF0C163152340AE96F20234E13DC89B"
           Name="Docs"             
           Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef ID="{44802E47-FE3F-4AB2-92BB-523A99E24B1D}" Name="DocTYpe"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{41F5A41B-BCC9-45B0-9CA5-48BB023713B8}" Name="Approver1"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{374F0F87-AFEB-4E88-A039-A3CADD24A5B1}" Name="Approver2"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{5DD956B5-65DD-4861-811F-42BE0C07B118}" Name="Author"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{257F1CC5-0DF4-420A-ACF1-8511FCD5240C}" Name="Chapter"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{2631BE05-A16D-4E41-948B-73F42D536705}" Name="ChapterNumber"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{7B08A524-E877-43C9-B8D5-A8143993B3B1}" Name="oiplbQmsDocumentSubject"/>
</FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

What should I do to dispaly the Word icon?

Comment: My Content Type that also inherits from Document gets the icon automatically, only difference in my Content Type xml is that I specify "Description" and Group" and specify Overwrite"TRUE".

Comment: I will check by giving the attribute `Overwrite` and let you know

Comment: Not sure why that would help though :/

Comment: Can there be something missing at other place?

Comment: it did not work sir. :-(

Comment: Try EnableContentTypes="True" on your list, that's another thing I have done on mine

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to deploy a document template with your contenttype

```
 <Folder TargetName="Forms/Docs" />
 <DocumentTemplate TargetName="DocumentTemplate.docx" />
```

The DocumentTemplate.docx can you deploy with a module.

You can also specify a documenttemplate manually.
Open your contenttype >  Advanced settings > Add your document template

Comment: Should not be needed. I have created a content type very similar to the one in the question, without document template, and I get an icon (not exactly the same as if I use a document template, but it do show a nice word icon)